# Is it better to have more cores or higher processor clock speed to decrease build time for iOS projects

Tags: macos, xcode, performance

I am trying to pick the most appropriate hardware to speed up build time for iOS projects - I don't know if I should favor faster processors (3.5 GHz) with fewer cores (6) or slower processors (2.7 GHz) with more cores (12).

Comment: I think of it as highway lanes. You can take a 2 lane road with a speed limit of 75, or a 4 lane road with a speed limit of 60. But the speed limit doesn't matter if you're stuck in bumper to bumper traffic - and during rush hour, there is *always* traffic. So long as you know how to switch lanes and when to pass, you will always arrive faster taking the wider highway, despite the lower speed limit. On the other hand, say there's no traffic. You will arrive faster going 75, but only marginally so in comparison. More cores >>>> clock speed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's great [article](http://create.pro/blog/need-lots-cores-faster-cpu-clock-speed-cores-ghz-multi-threading-hyper-threading-explained/) about this subject.

> **More cores, slower clock speed**
>
> Pros
>
> - Applications that support multi-threading will greatly benefit from having a higher number of cores at their disposal
> - Increasing the amount of cores in your CPU is a cost effective way of increasing performance
> - Multi-threading support for applications will continue to improve over time
> - You will be able to run more apps at once without seeing performance drops
> - Great for running multiple virtual machines
>
> Cons
>
> - Lower single threaded performance than a higher clock speed processor
>
> **Fewer cores, higher clock speed**
>
> Pros
>
> - Better single threaded performance
> - Lower cost option
>
> Cons
>
> - Fewer cores to split between applications
> - Not as strong multi-threading performance

Since Xcode is able to compile sources in parallel, I'd recommend using more cores. To compile one file You don't need so much speed on one core.

Comment: Your post makes a great deal of sense in the real world - in my fantasy I actually want *both*. There's no satisfying some people ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something to consider here is that software builds are often I/O intensive rather than CPU intensive. Increasing disk speed or bus speed would help a bit here, but probably not significantly. The details, of course, would depend on the details of your project. Because disk I/O would be the bottleneck, I'm not sure if the distinction between higher clock speeds or more cores would be at all significant.